# Running application with sbt and Akka Microkernel

Tags: scala, sbt, akka, sbt-native-packager, akka-cluster

Can I use both in my project?

Previously I had only object extending `App` trait, but since I started using `Microkernel` I need to have class extending `Bootable` trait.

Let's say that I have something like this:

```
lazy val backend = (project in file("backend"))
  .enablePlugins(AkkaAppPackaging)
  .enablePlugins(UniversalPlugin)
  .settings(
    name := "backend",
    mainClass in Compile := Some("backend.Backend"),
    libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.backend,
    javaOptions in run ++= Seq("-Djava.library.path=./sigar"),
    fork in run := true)
  .dependsOn(api)
  .aggregate(api)
```

and Backend class like this:

```
class Backend extends Bootable {

      val system = ActorSystem("mobile-cluster")

      def startup() = {
        FactorialBackend startOn system
      }

      def shutdown() = {
        system.shutdown()
      }
    }
```

I cannot start app with `sbt run` (there is an error about missing static main method), but it works with Microkernel, when I run `sbt stage` and next start application using generated script it works fine.

When I'm using something like this:

```
object Backend extends App {

      val system = ActorSystem("application")

      FactorialBackend startOn system
    }
```

I can start app with `sbt "project backend" "run"`, but Microkernel doesn't work anymore.

What can I do with that?
Should I have separate files for starting application with Microkernel and sbt or separate build configurations?

I need to have a production version of application using Microkernel and I also want to just run and debugging my application during development using sbt.

I tried to use the same class or object extending both, App and Bootable trait or configure sbt.build to have separate configuration for Microkernel and `sbt run`, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create another module, put there bootable class and add additional build configuration:

```
lazy val backend = (project in file("backend"))
  .settings(
    name := "backend",
    libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.backend,
    javaOptions in run ++= Seq("-Djava.library.path=./sigar"),
    // this enables custom javaOptions
    fork in run := true)
  .dependsOn(api)
  .aggregate(api)

lazy val boot = (project in file("boot"))
  .enablePlugins(AkkaAppPackaging)
  .enablePlugins(UniversalPlugin)
  .settings(
    name := "boot",
    mainClass in Compile := Some("com.example.Boot"),
    libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.backend,
    // this enables custom javaOptions
    fork in run := true)
  .dependsOn(backend)
  .aggregate(api, backend)
```

Right now I can run

```
sbt "project backend" "run"
```

and

```
sbt "project boot" "stage"
```

Comment: This is a nice solution. I first though of a companion object extending your `Bootable` class with `App` and just executes the `startup` method, which is a fine solution if you don't have a lot going on in the boot section. BTW, thanks for trying my activator :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need 2 modules for it.

you can run the microkernel with the following command

sbt "project backend" "run-main akka.kernel.Main Backend"

Answer (score 0):

Perform these instructions by sbt console:

```
runMain akka.kernel.Main Backend
```